# How does changing the characteristic of a field affect irreducible factorization or proofs about irreducible factorization?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic 0 , and let $g(x) \in k[x]$ be a polynomial of degree $d$ which is not a square. Consider
$$
f:=y^2-g(x) \in k[x, y]
$$
Show this polynomial $f$ is irreducible in $k[x, y]$

Proof: contemplate a factorization
$$
y^2-g(x)=f=\left(a_n(x) y^n+\cdots+a_0(x)\right)\left(b_m(x) y^m+\cdots+b_0(x)\right) .
$$
Expanding the right hand side shows $m+n=2$ and that $\lambda:=a_n(x)=b_m(x)^{-1}$ are scalars. So this means if either $m=0$ or $n=0$, one of the factors on the right is a unit, and this gives a trivial factorization. So it remains to rule out the case $m=n=1$. In this case, we have:
$$
y^2-g(x)=\left(\lambda y+a_0(x)\right)\left(\lambda^{-1} y+b_0(x)\right)=y^2+\left(\lambda b_0(x)+\lambda^{-1} a_0(x)\right) y+a_0(x) b_0(x)
$$
Matching coefficients shows that: $b_0(x)=-\lambda^{-2} a_0(x)$ and therefore $g(x)=-\lambda^{-2} a_0(x)^2$. Since we assumed $g(x)$ is not a square, this is impossible! Thus the only factorizations of $f$ involve a unit, so it is irreducible, whence prime, in $k[x, y]$.

My question is whether this proof also works in the case where we change the characteristic of our field. I'm not quite sure, but if $\lambda$ equals the characteristic of our field, would we have problems?

Comment: It seems that the same proof works for characteristic other than $0$; in the process, you can assume $\lambda=1$ because it must be a unit, so it cannot equal the characteristic and it gives you no problem. In fact, the algebraic closeness of the field seems irrelevant as well.

Comment: @david h - in characteristic $2$ it follows $y^2-x^2=(y-x)^2$ which is reducible.